# Streamlining conditional statements (if statement) in bash

Tags: bash, syntax, if-statement, conditional-statements

My question is more so a question about code efficiency and simplicity than it is about simply completing a task. The scenario is as such: I would like to create a bash script that uses a for loop to iterate through /Users when it is in each users home directory I want it to see if two different directories exist in the style of:

```
for USER in /Users/*; do
    if [ -d "$USER/Library/Caches/com.spotify.Client" ]; then 
        rm -rf "$USER/Library/Caches/com.spotify.Client"
```

...but I need to check for multiple directories. How do I accomplish this in the most elegant way? I would like to avoid using a series of if statements but don't know the best way to accomplish this.

Finally, I would like to use the find command to find a file, then set the result of the find (i.e. the path to the found file) to a variable and input it into another command. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your requirements, I would nest the `for` loops:

```
subdirs=(
    "Library/Caches/com.spotify.client"
    "some/other/subdir/"
)

for homedir in /Users/*; do
    for subdir in "${subdirs[@]}"; do
        dir="$homedir/$subdir"
        if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
            rm -rf "$dir"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Could I have done the same thing with a here file?

Comment: There's a typo in the above: `subddir` should be `subdir`. Furthermore, the multi-line variable assignment doesn't work on my bash 3.2.48 system (Mac OS X 10.7.4) - only uses the first line.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo: To use a here document (substitute actual line breaks for `\n`; do _not_ quote the paths):  `read -r -d '' subdirs<<EOF\nLibrary/Caches/com.spotify.client\nsome/other/subdir\nEOF`

Comment: D'oh! I've fixed the typo and iteration over the array (in Bash, `x=( ... )` is an array, not multi-line variable assignment; for more: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)

Comment: Alternately, without using an array, you could use `for subdir in "a/b" "y/z"; do … done;`

Comment: @DavidWolever: Thanks for clarifying the array issue; as for not using an array variable: see my answer (inspired by your answer and comments) below for also making do with only _one loop_.

Answer (score 1):

The following builds on @David Wolever's answer above; these versions are shorter and let the shell do more globbing up front.

Inline, single-loop version without use of intermediate (array) variable:

```
for dir in /Users/*/'Library/Caches/com.spotify.client/' /Users/*/'some/other/subdir/'; do
    [[ -d "$dir" ]] && rm -rf "$dir"
done
```

Array-variable version:

```
subdirs=(
    'Library/Caches/com.spotify.client/'
    'some/other/subdir/'
)

for subdir in "${subdirs[@]}"; do
    for dir in /Users/*/"$subdir"; do 
        [[ -d "$dir" ]] && rm -rf "$dir"
    done
done
```